# Is Java ignoring my -Xmx and -Xms parameters?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

A command line starts Gradle, which in turn spawns a Java process to start Jetty with our app. The app may quickly need a lot of memory. We have therefore requested a startup with a 2Go heap, and the same as maximum heap size.

```
// Launch server
task appRun (type:Exec)  {

/*  ... irrelevant bits removed, establishing the variables ... */

    executable javaExec
    args "-Xmx2g", "-Xms2g", "-DwaConfigFolder=config", "-Djava.io.tmpdir="+JETTY_TEMP_FOLDER, '-jar', jettyFile, "--path" , webApp, "--config" , jettyHttpsConfFile, warFile
}
```

However, as soon as the app gets to work, Java bumps into the 1Go default limit, and the CPU goes crazy, probably garbage-collecting the tiny corners left over in the tight memory.

[image]

Is it possible that the parameters are being ignored or overridden ?

Comment: Please provide the relevant configuration block from `build.gradle`.

Comment: How much *physical* memory do you have?

Comment: The machine has 16Go. What configuration block would be relevant ? It's just an exec task. I'm updating the message to show it.

Comment: Do you define `commandLine` as well?

Comment: No we don't define `commandLine`.